# How can I set the value of a component's variable from the router, in React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on an SPA with **React 18** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I have a Movielist component that I wish to make *reusable*, by which I mean it should display the movies on the *top_rated* endpoint as well as those on the *now_playing* endpoint, (depending on which the active route is).

For this purpose, in the App.js I have:

```
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Topbar from './components/Topbar/Topbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Movielist from './components/Movielist/Movielist';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Topbar />

      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Movielist listMovies="now_playing" />} />
          <Route path="/top-rated" element={<Movielist listMovies="top_rated" />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In `Movielist.jsx` I have:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Movielist.css';
import Moviecard from '../Moviecard/Moviecard';

function Movielist() {

    const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    let listMovies = 'top_rated';

    const getMovies = async () => {
        const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/movie/${listMovies}`, {
            params: {
                api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            }
        });

        setMovies(results);
    }

    const displayMovies = () => {
        return movies.map(movie => (
            <Moviecard
                key={movie.id}
                movie={movie}
            />
        ))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovies();
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="page-title">Now Playing</h1>
            <div className="row list">
                { displayMovies() }
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Movielist;
```

Above, the `listMovies` variable is hardcoded: `let listMovies = 'top_rated'`.

#### The goal

I want the `listMovies` variable to be dynamic instead, with *its value coming from the active route*.

##### How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: You can specify `route variables` in `React Router Dom` i.e. <Route path="path_to_component/:variable_name"></Route>`. You can access the `variable_name` from the component using the `useParams()` hook from `React Router Dom`. See https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params

Comment: I don't want the variable i the URL. I want the routes clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While going through your solution I can see that you are only one step away from achieving this.

When providing the **MovieList** for both your routes, you are passing a prop called *listMovies* which holds the url that is going to help you fetch the resources you need based on the route.

Simply make use of this prop inside your component and you will achieve what you need while keeping your routes clean.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Movielist.css';
import Moviecard from '../Moviecard/Moviecard';

function Movielist({listMovies}) {

    const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const location = useLocation();

    const getMovies = async () => {
        const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/movie/${listMovies}`, {
            params: {
                api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            }
        });

        setMovies(results);
    }

    const displayMovies = () => {
        return movies.map(movie => (
            <Moviecard
                key={movie.id}
                movie={movie}
            />
        ))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovies();
    }, [location])

    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="page-title">Now Playing</h1>
            <div className="row list">
                { displayMovies() }
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Movielist;
```

Comment: I tried the above, but only the _now_playing_ endpoint is called.

Comment: If that is the case, I believe your other route might not be working properly. React Router Dom might be rendering, for every route, the MovieList component whose listMovies prop is set to now_playing.

Comment: I have `<Route path="/" element={<Movielist listMovies="now_playing" />} />
          <Route path="/top-rated" element={<Movielist listMovies="top_rated" />} />`.

Comment: I was running a version of your project locally and it seemed to work fine.